# Native Event Supported Parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Anyone know if/where documentation exists that outline parameters for native Aura events like e.force:showToast?  In all the examples I have found they show "title" and "message" but I was curious if there are additional parameters like "severity" or others.

What I am looking for would be similar to this snippet

```
var showToast = $A.get('e.force:showToast');

showToast.setParams(
    {
         'title': 'Failure: ',
         'message': "Custom Message Here",
         'severity':"Error"
    }
);

showToast.fire();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the documentation, available in your [production/developer org](https://login.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app) or [sandbox org](https://test.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app). You'll need to log in in order to see them. Check out the Events menu on the left, then open the namespace, and then click on the event. All publicly available parameters will be available there.

[image: force:showToast documentation]